# writing a function that takes in a user input

Tags: clojure

I'm relatively new to this language e.g. like learning it right now, I'm looking online and can't make heads or tails of this language.

I need to be able to make a function named divisors which takes in user input and will return all numbers from 2 √ inclusive.

here is the code that I have so far.

```
(defn divisors[n]
(->> (range 2 (inc (quot n 2)))
(filter #(zero? (rem n %)))))
```

this is what the end product should look like.

```
(get-divisors 4)
=> (2)
(get-divisors 101)
=> (2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
```

Comment: This is far too broad. Have a start [here](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/tutorials/introduction.html#the-basics) though. Scroll down to "Functions: Defining Your Own". Once you've written up some code and have a specific question, we can help you with that.

Comment: ok cheers I'll take a look now thanks for the help on that

Comment: I've made a start on the function now. just wondering on the rest in the post

Comment: Your code works. 101 is prime afaik. It doesn't have any other divisors. Your test case is wrong.

Comment: I just realised that from further testing of the code that I have, I wonder why how my tutor got it wrong.

Comment: They got it exceedingly wrong. I don't think it's possible for a number to have divisors of `(2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)` (except maybe some huge number). That has to be a trick question/test case.

Comment: more than likely, I've emailed the tutor now about it, just waiting on a reply from him.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186247/discussion-between-carcigenicate-and-modzking4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never mind I was executing the code wrong when entering my input for the [n] wrong. when the code was compiled I was just using the value 4 and getting the same value back in its place.

```
(defn divisors[n]
(->> (range 2 (inc (quot n 2)))
(filter #(zero? (rem n %)))))
```

this code works as long as you input your text in your right format e.g. once the code is compiled you need to use the format (divisors 4) which gives the user the answer (2)